# Eclipse console not parsing input properly

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem with the Eclipse console where it appears that my input is not being passed in properly. This is with a new Hello World C++ project. Eclipse console loops endlessly, but running from Windows command line or Cygwin terminal works fine. I've played about with the console encoding to no avail.

```
int main() {
    int times;
    while (true) {
        cout << ">> " << flush;

        // Get input from the command line
        string input;
        getline(cin, input);

        cout << "This is loop number " << times << endl;
        times++;

        if (input == "exit") {
            cout << "Exiting" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Eclipse console:

```
>> exit
This is loop number 1
>> exit
This is loop number 2
>> exit
This is loop number 3
>> exit
This is loop number 4
>> exit
This is loop number 5
>> exit
This is loop number 6
>> exit
This is loop number 7
>>
```

Windows command line:

```
C:\Users\Andy>eclipse-workspace\stacktest\Debug\stacktest.exe
>> exit
This is loop number 1
Exiting
```

**EDIT**

With thanks to @Armin it seems that Eclipse is inserting a new line at the end of the input.

```
>> hello
This is loop number 0


Size of input6   Input: 'hello
'
Char: h   int representaion: 104
Char: e   int representaion: 101
Char: l   int representaion: 108
Char: l   int representaion: 108
Char: o   int representaion: 111
Char: 
   int representaion: 13
```

Comment: Apart from the obvious syntactic error of a missing }, it works fine even in eclipse. The program is exiting properly. I think you don't seem to realise the program has exited.

Comment: That's just a copy-pasta error. The program is definitely not exiting.

Comment: I've edited the post to illustrate the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. On my machine it works.

So the only reason, why it would not work is: "exit" is not equal to input. There may be a CR or LF or CR/LF or other character at the end of the input. Or, we have different char Types.

Please run the following test program:

```
include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    int times{ 0 };
    while (true) {
        std::cout << ">> " << std::flush;

        // Get input from the command line
        std::string input{};
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        std::cout << "This is loop number " << times << std::endl;
        times++;

        // Test Begin ----------------------------------------
        std::cout << "\n\nSize of input" << input.size() << "   Input: '" << input << "'\n";
        for (char c : input) {
            std::cout << "Char: " << c << "   int representaion: " << static_cast<unsigned int>(c)<< '\n';
        }
        // Test End----------------------------------------

        if (input == "exit") {
            std::cout << "Exiting" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am really curious, what the result will be . . .

Comment: Yes you're right, Eclipse console is inserting a new line.